# Laravel 5: ErrorException: Undefined property: PostsControllerTest::$client

Tags: php, unit-testing, oop, laravel

Testing a Controller in Laravel I get the following error:

```
ErrorException: Undefined property: PostsControllerTest::$client
```

This is what my test looks like:

```
<?php 

class PostsControllerTest extends TestCase {

    public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->client->request('GET', 'posts');
    }
}
```

It makes a get request to the /posts URI and I expect to get a **NotFoundHttpException**

And not an undefined property error exception. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like:

```
$this->client->request('GET', '/');
```

calls the Symfony\Component\DomCraw

and

```
$this->call('GET', '/');
```

calls the Illuminate\Http\Response

So, just using call instead of client->request, resolved the issue.